# how create an Android app using Cordova framework and VisualStudio2015

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to build simple Android application by C#. Someone suggested `Cordova framework` . I don't know how to worki with Cordova. How to start with it and what tools that I need to install it if I will use Cordova and if there is easier way to build my android app than Cordova please suggest it. My programming tools (C# ,ASP.NET MVC5 forms, SQL Server , HTML5 , Javascript, CSS3, jQuery, Ajax, Json.

Comment: Cordova has nothing to do with C#.  You may want Xamarin.

Comment: Either way, you're looking for the documentation.

Comment: You only need to google: "best tool for developing mobile app using c#", then you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also started to develop a cross platform app recently and had a closer look on [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com). Xamarin relies mainly on C#, so maybe you will want to check it out, though I must say that I decided to not use it. I wasn't sure if there will still remain an advantage in terms of time because I need more control over my code for my app, but maybe it will be good for your project. As I have seen from several posts developing seemed to become somehow more time-consuming when you need very specific features of a certain OS or want to include your own (native) libraries. But as I said, I did not use a cross platform tool, so I can't tell you about my personal experiences.

On the other hand, I think I will try Cordova to build an Android App from a small web app written in java script. To get started you can check out the [cordova getting started guide](https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted), but as far as I know Cordova does not support C#. I also found [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) which looks pretty promising, maybe you find those results of my last research also helpful..

Comment: thanks for help , just by following the https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted , finally I will build andy app ? or it will be very simple ? .. actually I am not working in mobile app field .. I'm .net developer but I need to integrate a part of android app in my graduation project so I search about the easier way to build this app quickly .. you know what I talk about

Comment: the guide will get you set up with everything you need to make an app, see the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/) for how to make your own app work. I think you want to avoid coding in java, so if you set up your web app with html5, css, js and so on you can turn it into an android app with cordova. I will use ist myself in few weeks, but currently I can only tell you what I found out during my research...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to build android applications using c# then use xamarin , else if you are looking for apache cordova then you just need apache cordova extension for visual studio , I myself have been using apache cordova for VS '15 for about 5 months or so . it is just as you have to know html and css , with javascript or typescript

Comment: what about cordova framework  ?

Comment: if you are talking about apache cordova on visual studio , then it is a good framework when you are familiar with html+css and javascript or typescript